# TCAdmin needs super user permissions despite using sudo and being su

Tags: dpkg, sudo

So I'm using Microsoft Azure's trial for my Ubuntu VM, I can't login into the 'root' user as I need to access it via username and private ssh key, however 'myusername' with sudo has allowed me to do everything that root does until now.

Using:

```
sudo wget http://www.tcadmin.com/installer/tcadmin-2-bi.noarch.deb;dpkg -i tcadmin-2-bi.noarch.deb
```

and the output after saving the file is the following -

> dpkg: error: requested operation requires superuser privilege

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of the following error:

> ```
> dpkg: error: requested operation requires superuser privilege
> ```

Is that `sudo` was executed only on the first command, the 2nd command was executed as regular user.

One simple solution will be:

```
sudo wget http://www.tcadmin.com/installer/tcadmin-2-bi.noarch.deb
sudo dpkg -i tcadmin-2-bi.noarch.deb
```

You can execute also:

```
sudo bash -c "wget http://www.tcadmin.com/installer/tcadmin-2-bi.noarch.deb ; dpkg -i tcadmin-2-bi.noarch.deb"
```

Also possible, download the file as regular user, and install it as root

```
wget http://www.tcadmin.com/installer/tcadmin-2-bi.noarch.deb; sudo dpkg -i tcadmin-2-bi.noarch.deb
```

Comment: AH! You star, yeah that command below unpacked it fine.. the file saved so just Azure being awkward I think. Thank you!

Comment: and done I believe.